# влучні українські еквіваленти для англійських слів "freebies", "free stuff" та "goodies"

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів, from-english, терміни

На деяких сайтах є розділи безкоштовного завантаження матеріалів — малюнків, текстів тощо.

Англійською існує три сталих вирази:

**freebies** - дослівно українською перекладається як халява й має негативне забарвлення.

**free stuff** - безкоштовні (безоплатні речі), якщо перекладати дослівно, проте такий переклад виглядає незграбно.
Ще однією вадою цього перекладу є довжина слів — надто довгі слова дуже погано вписуються в меню веб-сторінок, особливо на двоязиких сайтах.

**goodies** - дослівно "солодощі" або "смаколики" - чудове слово, проте я не певна, що український читач сприйме це слово як еквівалент безкоштовного завантаження матеріалів з сайту.

Чи Вам траплялося влучне й *коротке* слово для позначення такого розділу?

Можливо вже склалась якась традиція найменування (на кшталт ЧаПи для розділу відповідей на поширенні запитання)?

Comment: Мені на думку спадає хіба що «подарунки» («подаруночки») і «даром» — але це, мабуть, зовсім не найкращі ідеї.

Comment: Може щось з цих [синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Comment: goodies на Dictionary.com пояснюється як будь-що приємне, як синонім подається tidbits - щось невеличке та приємне. І те і інше можна перекласти як "фішки" у розмовному значенні. Не знаю чи можна розділ безкоштовного завантаження так назвати, бо "фішкою" сайт може бути будь-що.

Comment: Мені з ходу придумалося "безкоштовинки". Для freebies точно підійде.

Comment: @Kreiri "безкоштовинки" - це варіант! Також на "словотворі" запропонували "безоплатки", але Ваш варіант, як на мене милозвучніше. Ви не проти додати ваш варіант на "Словотвір?" (https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/fribiz) - радо за нього голосуватиму!

Comment: @KiraMakogon у мене нема там акаунта, вибачте

Comment: @Kreiri я можу додати, згадавши Вас, як автора у коментарях

Comment: @KiraMakogon можете додати, якщо хочете

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мені здається в українській мові немає однослівних відповідників цим словам.
 
Насамперед, потрібно зазначити, що ці слова тяжко перекласти влучно навіть декількома словами, вони занадто універсальні і можуть приймати занадто багато значень. В даному випадку, варіюється лише контекст і забарвлення.

Я скористуюся [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=goodies) як словником сленгових виразів для трактування слів із точки зору простих людей та [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com) як офіційним словником, хоча по факту можна скористуватися будь-яким іншим офіційним словником.

1. Згідно із [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=goodies),

   > ..*goodies* can be whatever you want them to be, like your number, hugs, kisses etc. So actually you are all right but there are other things other than those!..
   >   ..something attractive or pleasing..

   [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com):

   > 1. things that are nice to eat, such as cakes and chocolates
   > 2. things that are nice to have but not essential

   Таким чином, це може бути буквально ЩО-ЗАВГОДНО, це не обов'язково їжа/солодощі(хоча  часто це так і це один із варіантів перекладу слова) і це щось, зазвичай, не безкоштовне.

   Переклад:

   > дослівно "солодощі" або "смаколики"

   не є істинним у всіх контекстах, а слово, котре б означало, щось приємне/привабливе мені не спадає на думку.
   Тому такий переклад є некоректним і коректний переклад стоїть під великим питання.
   Будь-які аргументовані варіанти можуть бути написані в коментарі до цієї відповіді і я додам їх сюди.
2. *free stuff* - ваш варіант *безкоштовні речі* я вважаю найближчим до оригіналу
   [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=goodies) найкраще пояснює це слово:

   > The word that can substitute everything.

   В даному випадку, слово *річ* може означати також що-завгодно, через це переклад вважаю коректним.
3. > freebies - дослівно українською перекладається як халява

   Фактично, так воно і є. [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=goodies) має таке основне значення [слова](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=freebies):

   > when you get something for free

   [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com):

   > something that someone gives you that you do not have to pay for

   І хоча, це не єдине значення слова, проте воно є основним. Єдина проблема тут, що  халява - це дещо не літературне слово.

Comment: Із _[халявою](http://sum.in.ua/s/khaljava)_ в мене ще асоціюється _[лафа](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?page=1482&wordid=46931)_ (_[лахва](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/25919-lakhva.html#show_point)_) — теж фамільярне слово, і значення схоже.

Answer (score 3):

Якщо матеріали інформаційні, то можна спробувати ***[цікавинки](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)***.

Але якщо це матеріали іншого виду, наприклад, програмне забезпечення, музика тощо, то, можливо, вони не асоціюватимуться у відвідувачів з цим словом, а натомість під таким заголовком вони очікуватимуть щось інше.

---

Дивився синоніми до слова *[лафа](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0&highlight=on)*/*[лахва](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0&highlight=on)* (яке в мене особисто чомусь асоціюється зі словом *халява*) на R2U і подумав про такі варіанти:

- ***пайдики*** (від діалектного *[пайда́](http://sum.in.ua/s/pajda)* «дарунок, талан»);
- ***поживки*** (див. *[пожи́вок](http://sum.in.ua/s/pozhyvok)*, *[пожи́ва](http://sum.in.ua/s/pozhyva)*);
- ***попаски*** (див. *[по́паска](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0&highlight=on)*, *[по́па́с](http://sum.in.ua/s/popas)*).

(Без зменшувальних суфіксів ці слова, по-моєму, мають засерйозну інтонацію, але з *-ик-*/*-ок-*, можливо, іноді застосовні.)

---

Також мені дуже подобається варіант ***безкоштовинки***, [запропонований Kreiri](/q/5790#comment9065_5790), — по-моєму, він вартий окремої відповіді.

Comment: так, Ви маєте рацію... шпалери для робочого столу в "цікавинках" мало хто шукатиме :(

Comment: Дійсно "безкоштовинки" - чудовий варіант, і вартий окремої відповіді! До речі на момент написання коментаря він має більше вподобань на "словотворі" (зі згоди @kreiri я додала цей варіант до обговорення).

Answer (score 1):

> [freebie](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/freebie) ​
>
> щось, що дається тобі без потреби платити за це,
> особливо як засіб залучення твоєї підтримки чогось або зацікавленості
> в чомусь:
>
> - Маркетингові представники компаній отримали ручки і кружки - звичайні *freebies.*
> - Журналісти отримали *freebie* обід.

Виходить, що *freebie* це як у нас *гречка* перед виборами. Отже, **гречка**.

Comment: та ж сама проблема, що й з халявою — негативне забарвлення... причому я віддаю результати своєї роботи для загального користування на некомерційному сайті, звісно, це робиться для привертання уваги до проєкту, над яким працюю, але в такому випадку це називається не "підкуп", а "представницькі витрати" :)